# I get error messages at terminal when I try to run manage.py runserver

Tags: python, python-3.x, django, python-2.7

I get error messages whenever I try to run manage.py,
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'PyShop.settings', but I have this module, named "PyShop.settings" in my folder.

```
C:\Users\uer\PycharmProjects\PyShop>python manage.py runserver
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "C:\Users\uer\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37-32\lib\site-packages\django\core\management\base.py", line 354, in run_from_argv
    self.execute(*args, **cmd_options)
  File "C:\Users\uer\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37-32\lib\site-packages\django\core\management\commands\runserver.py", line 61, in execute
    super().execute(*args, **options)
  File "C:\Users\uer\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37-32\lib\site-packages\django\core\management\base.py", line 398, in execute
    output = self.handle(*args, **options)
  File "C:\Users\uer\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37-32\lib\site-packages\django\core\management\commands\runserver.py", line 68, in handle
    if not settings.DEBUG and not settings.ALLOWED_HOSTS:
  File "C:\Users\uer\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37-32\lib\site-packages\django\conf\__init__.py", line 82, in __getattr__
    self._setup(name)
  File "C:\Users\uer\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37-32\lib\site-packages\django\conf\__init__.py", line 69, in _setup
    self._wrapped = Settings(settings_module)
  File "C:\Users\uer\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37-32\lib\site-packages\django\conf\__init__.py", line 170, in __init__
    mod = importlib.import_module(self.SETTINGS_MODULE)
  File "C:\Users\uer\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37-32\lib\importlib\__init__.py", line 127, in import_module
    return _bootstrap._gcd_import(name[level:], package, level)
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 1006, in _gcd_import
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 983, in _find_and_load
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 965, in _find_and_load_unlocked
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'PyShop.settings'

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:
...
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'PyShop.settings'
```

Comment: you should enable the virtual environment before running the runserver

Answer (score 0):

This could be a pathing issue. I'd recommend putting a blank __ init __.py file into your directory. No spaces between init and __.

Also, have you tried python3 instead of python?

python3 manage.py runserver

You could also try giving the direct path to PyShop.settings.

```
import os

current_directory = os.getcwd()
direct_path = f"{current_directory}\\PyShop.settings"
```

On second thought:

Are you trying to import a .settings? If so, you will need to find another way to import this rather than 'import PyShop'. Python expects a module (like PyShop.py) rather than (PyShop.settings)

Comment: I imagine you've already done this, but make sure you have before running manage.py

in terminal:
django-admin.py startproject Yourprojectname


Double-check that you're in the right directory: 
"cd YOUR PROJECTAPP NAME" and then run the "python manage.py runserver" again. Confirm that you only have one "manage.py" module.